# I can't view any details from pubspec.yaml

Tags: flutter

I can't access and read any file from my pubspec.yaml,i tried flutter clean is not working and all my lib folders can access the material ui,google font or any packages I installed in the pubspec.yaml
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CR5sj.jpg)

Comment: Double check the folder opened in your vs code. it that is  correctly pointing to the project directory ? Then navigate to the vs code terminal and run `flutter pub get` and if that works then your pubspec.yaml is working and try to reopen file either in vscode or any other text editor.

Answer (score 0):

In settings, do `Invalidate Cache and Restart` and then check if your pubspec.yaml file is opening or not.